# What do you call the behavior of someone being a regular customer in English?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, verbs

In my mother tongue there is a verb called '帮衬', which means someone being a regular customer of (a store, merchant, etc.) of another person to support her business, satisfy their own needs and save money.

Is there any similar behavior in your country in which someone regularly go to a shop(or other commercial place) and consume?  in order to support that shop, enjoy the needed goods/service and save money. 
(he regularly___that shop because the boss is nice, the goods/service is of high quality and the price is reasonable) .

What do you call that behavior in English?(it doesn't necessary be a verb, phrase work well if it convey similar meaning in English.), thanks.

Comment: Probably "support" comes close to the idea you want to express: http://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese//dictionary.php?word=%E5%B8%AE%E8%A1%AC

Comment: @Josh he is not merely supporting his friend, but also benefiting himself.

Comment: Yes, that is explained in the sentence, but I was thinking what term would fit in your example. "Mutual support" would convey the idea.

Comment: i think your terms is not specific enough to convey that part of 'frequently buying to'.

Comment: Maybe not, but there is probably no precise translation for the expression you are looking for. It is a cultural thing, and "mutual" probably is as close as you can get.

Comment: Something like **collaborated with** or **joined forces with** might work.

Comment: you can talk about something being a ***good deal all the way around*** meaning it’s good for me (I get low prices) and good for him (he gets some business)  But I don’t know a single word for it. maybe it’s a *symbiotic relationship* but I don’t think I’d really use that except when trying to be a bit nerdy.

Comment: @Josh  probably, i shall revise my question then.

Comment: @Steve Lovell  i think that's not specific enough.

Comment: @Jim  i think that doesn't address his behavior well.

Comment: He regularly ***frequents*** that shop because the boss is nice, the goods/service is of high quality and the price is reasonable.  I like ***giving them my business*** because they act like they care and treat me with respect.

Comment: there is the term "loyal customer" ... which to me means more than a regular or frequent customer but a customer that has some level of an emotional reluctance to sometimes shop at a competitor ... it's not a perfect term for your question but it is certainly a common term

Comment: @Jim  frequent is a good word, but the latter terms doesn't seem good after i look up the Freedictionary. you might want to post your answer.

Comment: @Tom22  that's a good terms that could be used in many context, you might want to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of a word that fulfills all of the nuanced meaning, but:

**Patronize** could fit your usage fairly well, at least relating to frequenting somewhere in order to support them, although not necessarily to your own financial benefit.

> **Patronize**
> *Verb*
>
> 1:  to act as patron of :  provide aid or support for *(The government patronized several local artists.)*
>
> 3:  to be a frequent or regular customer or client of *(A restaurant much patronized by celebrities.)*

<sup>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patronize)</sup>

Note that it can also mean that you are being condescending towards someone.

Comment: thanks, is that word used in daily life often?

Comment: I think patronise lacks the "mutual convenience" aspect that OP is referring to.

Answer (score 2):

In Germany one would probably call it a 'Stammkunde' for an individual or 'Stammkundschaft'  for a group (say in a pub). In English the closest would probably be a 'regular customer' or simply 'regular' for short.

Comment: @user239460 - I've used "regular" as a verb before. "I regulared that bar back in college."

Comment: @SomethingDark  it can be, but i think it's not specific enough, though it can be understand as well.

Answer (score 1):

An understated way of expressing the concept would be to refer to the customer as a "repeat customer." You would not be explicitly characterizing the customer's frame of mind, yet your listeners/readers would apprehend your message.

Comment: as tom22 mentioned before, 'loyal customer' would be more specific.